# How to merge two csv files by adding the values of a column as a list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am starting using pandas dataframes and I am stuck at this point. I am doing image segmentation from real-time traffic images. Thus, I need to order the information in a proper way, basically  I have two csv files with `N` rows as follows:

`File1.csv`

```
Id  Cam_id  Image                                            Timestamp
0   1501    https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00
1   1502    https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00
2   1503    https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00
...
```

`File2.csv`

```
Id  Detection_Class  Detection_Score
0      3            0.9345
1      82           0.9016
2      73           0.1456
0      3            0.9283
1      1            0.8499
2      1            0.4658
3      3            0.9944
4      1            0.3422
5      3            0.2174
...
```

Every time the `Id` counter of my `File2.csv` starts again with 0 it means that it is counting the objects from a new image of my `File1.csv` in the image column.

What I am trying to achieve is to merge the files in a way that I can get a list of the column values from `Detection_Class` and `Detection_Score`. Then, add them to a cells in two new columns as below:

```
Id  Cam_id  Image                                            Timestamp           Detection_Class  Detection_Score
0   1501    https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00     [3,82,73]       [0.9345,0.9016,0.1456]
1   1502    https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00     [3,1,1,3,1,3]   [0.9283,0.8499,0.4658,0.9944,0.3422,0.2174]
...
```

How I can accomplish this?
Any further help will be appreciated

Comment: And all the `Image` in `df1` are different? Also, is the `Id` in `File1.csv` increasing by `1`?

Comment: Yes, @QuangHoang all the values in ```Image```  are different. Also the ```Id``` is increased by ```1``` in ```File1.csv```. Sorry not to mention that ```Images``` rows could be a very large number, as well as the ```Id``` in ```File2.csv``` because it could detect ```N``` objects of every image.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `cumsum()` to group the `Id` blocks in `File2.csv`, then `merge` and `groupby`:

```
(df2.assign(Id=df2.Id.eq(0).cumsum()-1)
    .merge(df1, on='Id')
    .groupby('Id')
    .agg({'Cam_id':'first','Image':'first','Timestamp':'first',          
          'Detection_Class':list, 'Detection_Score':list})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
Id    Cam_id  Image                                   Timestamp                  Detection_Class     Detection_Score
--  --------  --------------------------------------  -------------------------  ------------------  ------------------------------------------------
 0      1501  https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00  [3, 82, 73]         [0.9345, 0.9016, 0.1456]
 1      1502  https://images.data.gov.sg/api/....jpg  2020-06-29T16:20:57+08:00  [3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]  [0.9283, 0.8499, 0.4658, 0.9944, 0.3422, 0.2174]
```

Comment: I was on the brink of changing the part *cum*sum, only to see it is generic: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cumsum%28%29